# Artisan Command Chamando Controller

Tags: laravel, artisan

Fiz uma função num `Controller` e criei um `Command` no **Artisan** para rodar essa função.

Segue:

### Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\EmpresaRating;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class CronController extends Controller
{
    public static function fireCron(){
        $ratings = EmpresaRating::where('quarentena', '=', 1)
        ->whereRaw("DATE_FORMAT(data_publicacao, '%Y-%m-%d') = '".date('Y-m-d')."'");

        if($ratings->exists()){
            $ratings->update(['quarentena' => 0]);
        }
    }
}
```

### CronCommand

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class CronCommand extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'cron_services';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Cron para atualizar avaliações que estão em quarentena após 7 dias.';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $controller = app()->make('App\Http\Controllers\CronController');
        app()->call([$controller, 'fireCron'], []);
    }
}
```

### Kernel

```
protected $commands = [
    \App\Console\Commands\Inspire::class,
    \App\Console\Commands\CronCommand::class,
];
```

Quando execute `php artisan cron_services` me dá esse erro:

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]  Call to a
>   member function getPath() on null

O que eu estou errando ?

Comment: É pra trazer uma lista. Laravel 5.1.

Comment: Então, duro que eu já resolvi isso com um Service Provider. Só tava dando um tempo na pergunta. Mas para efeito de resposta, eu coloquei um `dd(1)` antes de chamar o EmpresaRating e ele matou o código ali mesmo.

Comment: Não mano. Não quero listar os registros. Eu apenas faço uma busca, pergunta se existe registro. Se sim, eu já mando um update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece que por algum motivo o Command não estava acessando meu Controller. Então fiz usando **Service Provider**.

Criei um provider chamado CronProvider:

### CronProvider

```
public function boot(){

}

public function register(){
   $this->app->singleton('App\Cron\Cron', function ($app) {
       return new Cron;
   });
}

public function provides(){
   return ['App\Cron\Cron'];
}
```

Criei uma pasta chamada Cron e criei dentro dela um arquivo chamado `Cron.php`.

### Cron

```
public static function isDeferred(){
   return true;
}

public function provides(){
   return [
      'App\Cron\Cron'
   ];
}

public function fireCron(){
   $ratings = EmpresaRating::where('quarentena', '=', 1)
   ->whereRaw("DATE_FORMAT(data_publicacao, '%Y-%m-%d') = '".date('Y-m-d')."'");

   if($ratings->exists()){
       $ratings->update(['quarentena' => 0]);
   }
}
```

Depois criei um `command` chamado `CronCommand`, não esquecendo do `use App\Cron\Cron` para chamar minha `class`.

### CronCommand

```
protected $signature = 'cron:services';

protected $description = '7 dias.';

use App\Cron\Cron;

public function __construct()    {
   parent::__construct();
}

public function handle(Cron $cron){
   $cron->fireCron();
}
```

Registrei no `Kernel.php` da pasta **Commands**.

```
protected $commands = [
    \App\Console\Commands\Inspire::class, 
    \App\Console\Commands\CronCommand::class
];
```

Registrei no arquivo `app.php` da pasta **config**.

```
App\Providers\CronProvider::class,
```

Depois rodei o commando:

```
php artisan cron:services
```

Funcionou!